# How do i use realsense, darknet and deproject_point_to_pixel() in python to calcualte size of an object

Tags: python, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, realsense

I want to run darknet with coco dataset to reognize apples in a picture. I want to now find the size of the apples (length and breatdth) by incorporating the depth frame. How do i go about this? I need the approximate dimensions of the area enclosed by the bounding box.
The code basically takes a color frame and then draws a bounding box around the object i want (apple). Now i want to find the size of the apple in real life. How do i use the depth frame, rgb frame and darknet to find the length and breadth of the apple? I dont need the height of the apple. Just the rough length and breadth( in this case, the dimensions of the bounding box in real life is good enough).
What is the easiest and simplest way to calculate this?[image]

```
import darknet
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyrealsense2 as rs

"""##############. Function definitions. ##################"""

#Define the detection function
def image_detection(image, network, class_names, class_colors, thresh):
    # Darknet doesn't accept numpy images.
    # Create one with image we reuse for each detect
    width = darknet.network_width(network)
    height = darknet.network_height(network)
    darknet_image = darknet.make_image(width, height, 3)

    #image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_resized = cv2.resize(image_rgb, (width, height),interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

    darknet.copy_image_from_bytes(darknet_image, image_resized.tobytes())
    detections = darknet.detect_image(network, class_names, darknet_image, thresh=thresh)
    darknet.free_image(darknet_image)
    image = darknet.draw_boxes(detections, image_resized, class_colors)
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), detections


# Initialize and declare the neural network along with data files, config files etc 
quantity_apples = []
config_file = "/home/jetson/Desktop/pano_l515/yolov4.cfg"
data_file = "/home/jetson/Desktop/pano_l515/coco.data"
weights = "/home/jetson/Desktop/pano_l515/yolov4.weights"

network, class_names, class_colors = darknet.load_network(
        config_file,
        data_file,
        weights,
        batch_size=1
    )

## Realsense from align-depth2color.py

# Create a pipeline
pipeline = rs.pipeline()

# Create a config and configure the pipeline to stream
#  different resolutions of color and depth streams
config = rs.config()

# Get device product line for setting a supporting resolution
pipeline_wrapper = rs.pipeline_wrapper(pipeline)
pipeline_profile = config.resolve(pipeline_wrapper)
device = pipeline_profile.get_device()
device_product_line = str(device.get_info(rs.camera_info.product_line))

config.enable_stream(rs.stream.depth, 1024, 768, rs.format.z16, 30)

if device_product_line == 'L500':
    print(device_product_line)
    config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 1280, 720, rs.format.bgr8, 30)
else:
    config.enable_stream(rs.stream.color, 640, 480, rs.format.bgr8, 30)

# Start streaming
profile = pipeline.start(config)

# Getting the depth sensor's depth scale (see rs-align example for explanation)
depth_sensor = profile.get_device().first_depth_sensor()
depth_scale = depth_sensor.get_depth_scale()
print("Depth Scale is: " , depth_scale)

# We will be removing the background of objects more than
#  clipping_distance_in_meters meters away
clipping_distance_in_meters = 1 #1 meter
clipping_distance = clipping_distance_in_meters / depth_scale

# Create an align object
# rs.align allows us to perform alignment of depth frames to others frames
# The "align_to" is the stream type to which we plan to align depth frames.
align_to = rs.stream.color
align = rs.align(align_to)


# Streaming loop
try:
    for i in range(0,2):
        # Get frameset of color and depth
        frames = pipeline.wait_for_frames()
        # frames.get_depth_frame() is a 640x360 depth image

        # Align the depth frame to color frame
        aligned_frames = align.process(frames)

        # Get aligned frames
        aligned_depth_frame = aligned_frames.get_depth_frame() # aligned_depth_frame is a 640x480 depth image
        color_frame = aligned_frames.get_color_frame()

        # Validate that both frames are valid
        if not aligned_depth_frame or not color_frame:
            continue

        depth_image = np.asanyarray(aligned_depth_frame.get_data())
        color_image = np.asanyarray(color_frame.get_data())

        dn_frame_width = 416
        dn_frame_height = 416

        frame_width = color_image.shape[1]
        frame_height = color_image.shape[0]

        #### Passing the image to darknet
        image, detections = image_detection(color_image, network, class_names, class_colors, thresh=0.05)


        for i in range(len(detections)):
            xc_percent = detections[i][2][0]/dn_frame_width
            yc_percent = detections[i][2][1]/dn_frame_height 
            w_percent = detections[i][2][2]/dn_frame_width
            h_percent = detections[i][2][3]/dn_frame_height
            xc = xc_percent*frame_width
            yc = yc_percent*frame_height
            w = w_percent*frame_width
            h = h_percent*frame_height
            xmin = xc - w/2.0
            ymin = yc - h/2.0
            xmax = xc + w/2.0
            ymax = yc + h/2.0


            #If object is detected, increase the count of the object in the frame
            if detections[i][0] == "apple":
                cv2.rectangle(color_image, (int(xmin),int(ymin)),(int(xmax),int(ymax)),(0,0,255),2)
                cv2.putText(color_image, "apple", (int(xmin), int(ymin-10)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0,0,255), 2)
        
        #cv2.imwrite(output_path, frame)            
        # Render images:
        #   depth align to color on left
        #   depth on right
        depth_colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(cv2.convertScaleAbs(depth_image, alpha=0.03), cv2.COLORMAP_JET)
        images = np.hstack((color_image, depth_colormap))
        cv2.imwrite("test_images.jpg", color_image)
        #cv2.namedWindow('Align Example', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        #cv2.imshow('Align Example', images)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        # Press esc or 'q' to close the image window
        #if key & 0xFF == ord('q') or key == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            #break
finally:
    pipeline.stop()
```

Comment: please show examples of the data you have and what are your current results on this data, highlighting the gap you are trying to solve.

Comment: @Shai I have added the code in the edit.